# Not enough values selecting into a table value

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the code:

```
create type emp_high_sal_ot is object
(
    full_name varchar2(64),
    phone_number varchar(20),
    salary number(10,2)
);
create type emp_high_sal_nt is table of emp_high_sal_ot;
```

and the following function doesn't compile:

```
create or replace function get_highest_paid_emps return emp_high_sal_nt 
AS
    rec emp_high_sal_nt;
    avg_sal NUMBER;
begin
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    INTO avg_sal
    FROM employees;
        
    SELECT last_name || ' ' || first_name, phone_number, salary
    INTO rec
    FROM employees
    WHERE salary > avg_sal;
    
    return rec;
end;
```

It says:

PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that?

You are trying to put 3 values (and multiple rows) into a single variable.

---

Use `BULK COLLECT INTO` and wrap the values in the object type:

```sql
create or replace function get_highest_paid_emps return emp_high_sal_nt 
AS
    rec emp_high_sal_nt;
    avg_sal NUMBER;
begin
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    INTO avg_sal
    FROM employees;
        
    SELECT emp_high_sal_ot(
             last_name || ' ' || first_name,
             phone_number,
             salary
           )
    BULK COLLECT INTO rec
    FROM employees
    WHERE salary > avg_sal;
    
    return rec;
end;
/
```

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (first_name, last_name, phone_number, salary) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 'Abbot', '0123456', 100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Betty', 'Baron', '1111111', 250000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 'Chris', '9876543', 300000 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_highest_paid_emps());
```

Outputs:

> | FULL_NAME | PHONE_NUMBER | SALARY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Baron Betty | 1111111 | 250000 |
> | Chris Carol | 9876543 | 300000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ebf494fe97eb1ccfcea4caa3ff637247)*